# (Interview question) Lasso vs PCA

Tags: pca, lasso, multicollinearity

If LASSO treats collinearity than why use PCA?
I did not understand the question properly and the interviewer was not ready to give any hints

Comment: I don't understand the question as formulated. Could you at least try to produce a grammatically meaningful sentence?

Answer (score 3):

LASSO is not really a treatment for collinearity; it is a method of variable selection and model building.  PCA does help with collinearity and does other things besides - it is a dimension reduction technique.

The proper treatment of collinearity depends on your  goals.  It could be ridge regression, PCA, dropping variables on substantive grounds, getting more data, elastic net or perhaps some other methods that I am forgetting.

Answer (score 0):

When features are colinear, it not only contains redundant information, but also make solutions unstable.

Lasso (minimizing L1) is a feature selection method that select a small set of features that best completes the task on hand. In this sense, it is filtering extra information and treating colinearity. It is a feature selection method, in which we drop some features.

PCA is SVD on sample covariance matrix, which achieve reduction of dimension. The components are latent, each can be a combination of all features. In this case we can possibly be using information from all features, but the components are not colinear.

By the way, minimizing L1 doesn't really mean feature selection, since it is possible to have a solution that has small values in all entries. But in practice usually some features contain more signal than others, so in many cases L1 minimizer can select the better features by zeroing out contribution from worse features before the better ones.

Comment: Multicollinearity increases variance, not bias.

Comment: you are right;p